# Copying a GpuMat row to a std::vector

Tags: c++, opencv, copy, gpu, stdvector

How can I transfer cv::gpu::GpuMat rows to std::vector with as little as possible copy operations?

The fastest way I can think of is:

```
GpuMat fooGpu(numRows, numCols, CV_32FC1);
Mat foo = fooGpu;

Mat fooRow = foo.row(i);

std::vector<float> vec;
vec.resize(numCols);

memcpy(&vec[0], fooRow.data, sizeof(float)*numCols);
```

But I'm not even sure if this works, because the fooRow content would have to be aligned...

Is there another (better) way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the method that does not produce any unnecessary copying:

```
GpuMat fooGpu(numRows, numCols, CV_32FC1);
std::vector<float> vec;
vec.resize(numCols);
fooGpu.row(i).download(Mat(vec).reshape(1/*channels*/, 1/*rows*/));
```

Comment: No, sorry. I tested it and it doesn't work. The Mat(vec) uses vec for initialization values but doesn't seem to point to vec's data, because after downloading, vec is still filled with zeros.
Mat m;
fooGpu.row(i).download(m);
vec = m;

works, but this again involves copying.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that`Mat(vec)` shares vector data, but vector has to be allocated for right length (`vec.resize(numCols);` is mandatory). If this code does not work then it is an OpenCV bug and should be reported on OpenCV bugtracker.

Comment: You're right. But the download() method seems to reallocate memory.

Comment: I've found the source of the problem and updated the answer: by default vector is converted to Mat having `vec.size()` rows and 1 column. But I think this case is a bug and going to submit a ticket.

Answer (score 1):

I think `std::copy` is better:

```
std::vector<float> vec;
vec.resize(numCols); 
std::copy(fooRow.data, fooRow.data + numCols, vec.begin());
```

Note that the second argument is : `fooRow.data + numCols`, as opposed to `fooRow.data + sizeof(float)* numCols`.

Also, in your code `vec.resize(numRows);` doesn't seem to be correct. It should be :

```
 vec.resize(numCols);
```

Because `fooRow` is ONE row, and has`numCols` number of values in it.

Comment: With the `back_inserter` the resize might not be needed and the resizings amortize to O(1) anyway, but I think a reserve won't be a bad idea, as you know the size anyway. Although it's a good idea to favor clean code over prematurely optimized code, we shouldn't give us dumber than we are.

Comment: You're right of course... and your code looks nicer. But I still wonder if I can access the GpuMat data directly. And if not: can I assume that the fooRow-data are aligned?

Comment: @Nawaz But now you have a `resize` and a `back_inserter`. Either use `reserve` or `vec.begin()`.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly [this](http://answers.opencv.org/question/3386/gpumat-and-stdvector/) post may answer your question.